# Draw three square using svg and make them a vertical arrangement

Tags: xml, layout, svg

The following is my code:

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1200px" height="1500px" viewBox="0 0 400 500" id="RoomsSVG">
  <svg id="Room1" width="1200px" height="500px" x="0px" y="0px">
    <rect id="Room1Rect" width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" />
  </svg>
  <svg id="Room2" width="1200px" height="500px" x="0px" y="500px">
    <rect id="Room2Rect" width="100%" height="100%" fill="green" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" />
  </svg>
  <svg id="Room3" width="1200px" height="500px" x="0px" y="1000px">
    <rect id="Room3Rect" width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

I want to draw three squares,they have different colors.And I want to make them a vertical arrangement,but the display is always wrong.The red color fill in the all screen(width:1200px,height:1500px).I don'n know why?I have already modified it for more than an hour,still so.Who can tell me the reason? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewBox` attribute cuts out a rectangle of width 400 and height 500 (in user coordinates). This means, only the topmost red rectangle is seen, all others lie outside the view box.

This is also the reason why you don't see the right margin of the box, as the red box is 1200 units wide, but the view box only shows what's in between 0 and 400.

Comment: What you mean is that the page show the picture in the viewBox of width 1200 and height 1500.But I set the viewBox of width 400 and height 500.Why does it become big?

Comment: SVG's coordinate space is abstract, i.e. it doesn't correspond to screen pixels, even if you say `1500px`. What you do is draw three squares on an abstract canvas, then cut out a rectangle from point `0,0` of width 400 and height 500, then stretch what you cut out to fit the specified width and height.

Comment: Ok,I know it,although not very understanding.Thank you!